# CGAL Install MacOS QT5

Tags: c++, qt, clang, cgal

I am trying to build one of the `cgal` demos [from the developer website](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/usage.html).

I have installed `cgal` using `brew install cgal`.
I also have installed `qt5` version 5.15.2 using `brew install qt5`

However, when I try to build a demo (I am looking at the same one given in the example `$HOME/CGAL-5.2.1/examples/Triangulation_`) I get a long error from `make` that I don't know how to interpret.

My computer is running OS X 11.0.1.
Clang is version 12.0.0

```
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:667:65: error: expected '>'
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && std::is_arithmetic_v<U> &&
                                                                ^
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:667:65: error: expected ',' or '>' in template-parameter-list
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:668:66: error: expected unqualified-id
                                     std::is_floating_point_v<T> == std::is_floating_point_v<U> &&
                                                                 ^
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:679:35: error: no type named 'Promoted' in namespace
      'QTypeTraits::detail'
using Promoted = typename detail::Promoted<T, U>::type;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:679:43: error: expected ';' after alias declaration
using Promoted = typename detail::Promoted<T, U>::type;
                                          ^
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:691:31: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace 'QTypeTraits'
constexpr inline QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U> qMin(const T &a, const U &b)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:693:28: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace 'QTypeTraits'
    using P = QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U>;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:694:5: error: unknown type name 'P'
    P _a = a;
    ^
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:695:5: error: unknown type name 'P'
    P _b = b;
    ^
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:699:31: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace 'QTypeTraits'
constexpr inline QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U> qMax(const T &a, const U &b)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:701:28: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace 'QTypeTraits'
    using P = QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U>;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:702:5: error: unknown type name 'P'
    P _a = a;
    ^
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:703:5: error: unknown type name 'P'
    P _b = b;
    ^
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:707:31: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace 'QTypeTraits'
constexpr inline QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U> qBound(const T &min, const U &val, const T &max)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:710:31: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace 'QTypeTraits'
constexpr inline QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U> qBound(const T &min, const T &val, const U &max)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/opt/homebrew/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:713:31: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace 'QTypeTraits'
constexpr inline QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U> qBound(const U &min, const T &val, const T &max)

fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 1):

A very late answer but my solution was to uninstall Qt6 so that you only have Qt5. It is possible you may have both installed. Header files from both can conflict and confuse make. To properly do so:

1. Find all of the Qt versions you have installed with Homebrew:

```
brew list | grep qt
# You should see something like "qt qt@5"
```

2. Remove `qt` (which is Qt6)

```
brew uninstall qt
```

You should now have only Qt5 left. Try doing the build again, see if the issue is fixed.

Comment: You might also be able to just do `brew unlink qt`, leaving it installed but not symlinked to the main `/usr/local/` hierarchy. Unlinking worked for me when I was facing similar issues.